# Java API Yandex с чем это есть

Tags: java, api

Такой вопрос, изучаю Java, знаю какие-то основы, наткнулся на ТЗ и хочу его выполнить:

Есть два конфигурационных файла

1. Конфигурационный файл (где хранятся настройки smtp сервера и другие настройки)
2. Файл шаблон письма, в котором есть 2 параметра для подстановки ФИО и телефона

При запуске программа должна подставить в шаблон письма параметры ФИО и телефон (прочитав их из конфигурационного файла) и отправить на адрес (*******.com) письмо.

В качестве SMTP сервера для отправки почты нужно использовать smtp.yandex.ru

**Я НЕ ПРОШУ** сделать за меня задание, я лишь хочу узнать что необходимо знать для выполнения (шаблоны, коллекции я хз, библеотеки) если у Вас есть литература, то рад буду увидеть ссылки, если такие вопросы тут запрещается выставлять, то простите